# Distinct by Category then Join all distinct values per Category in one column

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Data:

```
CategoryId  Value     
1            val1   
1            val2  
1            val2
2            test1  
2            test1  
3            data1  
3            data2 
3            data2
```

---

the output that i want is like this:

```
CategoryId        Value
1                  val1. val2.
2                  test1.
3                  data1. data2.
```

output should be Distinct in CategoryId and only distinct values per category should be displayed and joined together in 1 column value. (Assume that the values are string values which are 1 to 3 sentences long).
How do i query this in LINQ? or how do i group it with the output that i wanted?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems you know what you want, where do you have the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GroupBy` CategoryId and `Join` the `Distinct` Values

```
var distinctCategory = categoryList.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
                                    .Select(x => new Category()
                                    {
                           CategoryId = x.Key,
                           Value = string.Join(". ", x.Select(y => y.Value).Distinct())
                                    });
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Z04AY

Comment: i can categorized them by ID but i dont know how to join the distinct values per category. Great Answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to group the values by category ID, and then take the distinct values within the group.

That can all be done with a single `GroupBy` call:

```
var query = input.GroupBy(
    item => item.CategoryId,              // Key projection
    item => item.Value,                   // Element projection
    // Result projection. (You may want to add ToList within the lambda to materialize.)
    (key, values) => new { Key = key, Values = values.Distinct() });
```

Here's a complete program with your example data:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = new[]
        {
            new { CategoryId = 1, Value = "val1" },
            new { CategoryId = 1, Value = "val2" },
            new { CategoryId = 1, Value = "val2" },
            new { CategoryId = 2, Value = "test1" },
            new { CategoryId = 2, Value = "test1" },
            new { CategoryId = 3, Value = "data1" },
            new { CategoryId = 3, Value = "data2" },
            new { CategoryId = 3, Value = "data2" },
        };

        var query = input.GroupBy(
            item => item.CategoryId,              // Key
            item => item.Value,                   // Element
            // Projection of results
            (key, values) => new { Key = key, Values = values.Distinct() });

        foreach (var element in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{element.Key}: {string.Join(", ", element.Values)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just do the grouping of value by category ID, then perform the `Distinct()` part when you consume:

```
var query = from item in input
            group item.Value by item.CategoryId;

foreach (var group in query)
{
    var values = group.Distinct();
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}: {string.Join(", ", values)}");
}
```

You *can* use `string.Join` within the query, of course - but I'd normally wait until the last possible moment to convert the logical data into a display representation. If you wanted to do that with the first example, you'd just use:

```
var query = input.GroupBy(
    item => item.CategoryId,              // Key projection
    item => item.Value,                   // Element projection
    // Result projection. (You may want to add ToList within the lambda to materialize.)
    (key, values) => new { Key = key, Values = string.Join(", ", values.Distinct()) });
```

Note that I've joined the values with a comma rather than a period. Your original expected output wouldn't be achievable with just `string.Join` and a period anyway, as you have a trailing period too. You *could* get that exact output with a projection then a `string.Concat` call, e.g.

```
foreach (var element in query)
{
    var periodValues = element.Values.Select(x => x + ". ");
    Console.WriteLine($"{element.Key}: {string.Concat(periodValues)}");
}
```

Comment: Please change separator to **". "**, it will be perfect.

Comment: @GaurangDave: It wouldn't quite match the OP's output anyway, given that there's a `.` at the *end* that way as well. I'll leave it this way as a more commonly-useful answer - and the presentation part is really somewhat separate from everything else anyway IMO. (Hence the last part of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working solution.

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 1,Value = "val1"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 1,Value = "val2"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 1,Value = "val2"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 2,Value = "test1"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 2,Value = "test1"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 3,Value = "data1"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 3,Value = "data2"});
data.Add(new Data(){CategoryId = 3,Value = "data2"});

var result = data.Distinct()
.GroupBy(d => d.CategoryId, d=>d.Value, (k,v) => new { Key=k, Values = v.Distinct()  } )
.Select(d => new Data()
{
    CategoryId = d.Key,
    Value = string.Join(". ", d.Values.ToList())
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The bulk of the code here is initialization, which can be simplified very significantly, even without any changes to your `Data` class. At the moment, we need to scroll to see the important part - if you reformatted it to use a single line per element instead of 5, the answer would be *much* more readable.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Thanks for suggestion. Hope now it is fine

Comment: Yes, much better. Admittedly I find an anonymous type simpler as then anyone can copy/paste/run the code, but that's a different matter.